# Custom emailing, or mailing software for a web app?

Tags: email, notifications

I see two options when it comes down to email communications with your users.

1. Sending emails from server based on some events (using [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) for example)
2. Using email software such as MailChimp, Constant Contact, or similar

Option 1 is good for general events but option 2 seems more suitable for newsletters, promotional activities, the ability for sales people to quickly draft emails, track responses, maintaining sales leads, etc. The downside is these tools can get quite expensive.

Is there a sweet spot between the two of them, or are companies like Groupon, Spotify, Apple, or other companies using both solutions?

UPDATE:

App events would require many more notifications (few per day sometimes) than those for sales (few per month). So applying option 2 for events would be uselessly costly.

Answer (score 0):

Some mail services offer an API that allows you to send mail through their service, when certain events occur, this way a mail service can be used for all your mailing needs.

This is good for many reasons, mainly not re-inventing the wheel ... There are many aspects of mailing that is not immediately obvious, that a specialized mailing service company would have solved for you.

That being said, being tied to a specific vendor also means that you are very dependent on that vendors services. If his API goes down, you cannot send mail.

I have seen many approaches to the email problem, and if I may generalize a little; I would say:

- Many small sites run their own, which works fine for a while.
- When the business grow to a medium to large size, the need for an email vendor emerges, and the business is likely to be able to spend the money it costs to have a professional mailing solution.
- When the business gets sufficiently large (think Apple, Facebook), they are likely to build their own solution - because the companys needs gets very large and very specific, and it gets harder to find a vendor that does just exactly what they want. And finally, large companies generally don't like to be very dependent on a specific vender.

Comment: Are you referring to email for events and notifications, those for sales, or both? Just added the update to post to clarify this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Manage your email campaign using statistical tracking, time sensitive autoresponders, custom subscription forms, personalized mailings, advanced real time graphical reporting, and more. That is iKode [Newsletter Software](http://www.phpnewsletter.org/).